# Certain blue pixels appear green and moving

Tags: windows-10, display

All of a sudden today, I started working on my laptop and it seems that anything a particular shade of *blue* on the screen is acting funny, for want of a better description.

I took a screenshot of my desktop, and surprisingly the funniness is preserved in the photo, and it appears to be particular values of colors so I can see the location in the picture preserved. I don't believe it is a screen issue per se, because when I take a screen capture using Snipping Tool and resize the image or move it around, the greenish-blue pixels move around too. They don't just stay local to one part of the screen, but stay with that part of the picture. This suggests the monitor, or Windows, may be having trouble displaying a certain value of blue now.

Because you won't be able to see if I just take a screen capture, I used a camera to take some pictures as best I could (the glare was really bad):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I imported the pictures and used Snipping Tool to capture the relevant part and circle where the greenish moving pixels can be seen. The greenish pixels are moving a little, not static, but confined to the general area circled.

Needless to say, this is concerning, especially since this the only laptop I have with me for the summer and it's not even mine. It's not extremely disruptive, but I don't know if this will get worse. Would anyone be able to tell me if this is a screen issue or a Windows issue? And how I would address it if it's the latter? (If it's the former, I suppose I'm screwed.)

**UPDATE:**
I am certain this must be a Windows issue now (thankfully, better software than hardware) because I just hibernated said laptop and went to dinner, and came back and now things are back to normal. I can no longer see the moving green pixels in the first 2 snapshots above, so somehow the issue must have gone away.

Has a display driver gone bad or something? Or could it actually be a screen issue, just not one that persists all the time?

Comment: Does it do the same on external output to another LCD?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Unfortunately, I have no way of testing since I don't have any monitors with me for the summer. If you see my update above, though, it isn't consistent (better than being permanent I suppose). I can't observe the problem anymore at the moment. Perhaps if I hibernate and boot up again, I will see it again. It sounds like a Windows issue in that case, not a screen issue.

Comment: I’ll disagree with your edit, clearing up after sleeping for awhile really points to a heat related hardware issue, not a windows issue.

Comment: @Tyson Before I was using it, it was turned off pretty much all day. I've been using it in the same way for weeks and I've never had any heat issues. I always hibernate, not sleep, and that is one reason why

Comment: What about reducing resolution and/or colour depth?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Good idea, I'll try that if it happens again (I'm hoping not though!)